# weird error when using javascript async/await syntax

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

I was trying to get a random user from the randomuser api. The code is from my vue frontend.

```
// api response
{ info: { // ommited }, results: [ {//random user data} ] }

// this works
async get_random_user() {
        const url = "https://randomuser.me/api/";
        const res = await fetch(url);
        const json_data = await res.json();
        const result = json_data.results[0];
        return result; 
    }

// this throws Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
async get_random_user() {
        const url = "https://randomuser.me/api/";
        const res = await fetch(url);
        const result = await res.json().results[0];
        return result; 
    }
```

Why the second function doesn't work?
Thanks.

Comment: What if you wrap (await res.json) in parentheses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const result = await res.json().results[0];
```

You are directly accessing **results** data ( which might not be assured/yielded yet) instead of waiting for the  **res.json()** to finish processing

EDIT

It is not assured that res.json() will yield any data yet, or there will be any proper response at all. So accessing data is not reasonable yet

await is getting called on results[0]
its not getting called on res.json();

**To simplify, what you are actually doing is this**

```
results = res.json();
const result = await results[0];
```

So there are two logical errors in this

Comment: I've got it now. I was taking my baby steps in js async/await syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

`await` expects a `promise` in return. `json()` returns such a promise, but `json().results` is just an `object` (which is even undefined at start). Thats why `await` doesn't work on that structure.

Answer (score 0):

Check if res.json().results is not an empty array;

```
const result = (await res.json()).results.[0];
```

Comment: thanks, I've got it now. `const result = (await res.json()).results.[0];` does work.